# Can I use Admob ads in 2 play console app?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, google-play-console

I have a play console account and I use Admob ads in my app. Suddenly I buy an app from a developer. App published on Google Play his play console account. My question is can I use my Admob ads in my buying apps? Already I use my Admob ads in my play console app. And my buying apps another play console.

Comment: You can create new app on Admob then you can create new ad ids and replace ad ids in new bought app.

Comment: I have another AdMob but an ad serving limit. that's why I need to know can I use same AdMob ads in two play console app

Comment: You can use same admob account. but you have to create different app on same account.
You cant use same app ids for 2 different apps.

Comment: ok, but Can have any effect on my play console?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it. just create another app in  admob create desired ads which are used in your new app get these ads credentials and replace it with existing ones.
it will work fine

Comment: Can have any effect on my play console?

Comment: No there won't be any effect